# Android Notifications not disappearing (Even with Auto_Cancel)

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have different notifications that each have a different bundle/activity associated with them. My problem is that they don't disappear once clicked. They aren't under ongoing notifications though and "clear" gets rid of them. Bellow is my code. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
 private void showNotification(Bundle b){
    CharSequence myText = b.getString("notifStr");

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_sample, myText,System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent i = new Intent(myContext, NewPlace.class);
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW + Integer.toString(b.getInt("id")));
    i.putExtras(b);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(myContext, 0, i, 0);

    notification.defaults |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(myContext, myText,myText, contentIntent);

    notifMan.notify(b.getInt("id"), notification);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Answer (score 2):

try changing:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

to

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Notification Documentation (Flags)

> public int defaults
>
> Since: API Level 1 Specifies which
>   values should be taken from the
>   defaults. To set, OR the desired from
>   DEFAULT_SOUND, DEFAULT_VIBRATE,
>   DEFAULT_LIGHTS. For all default
>   values, use DEFAULT_ALL.

Comment: Dont say should, try all options.